# How To Stop Timer On function call react-native-timer-countdown

Tags: react-native

I have implemented react-native-timer-countdown package and it works fine just like given in the following example
https://github.com/avid21/react-native-timer-countdown

But I want the timer to stop on a function call rather when the mentioned time elapses.
Can this be done using this package? If not then please suggest me some other way by which I can do it.

Thanks In advance.